# WAS migration to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websphere

We are in process of migrating our WAS based application to Tomcat9. And we have correctly setup queue connection for our MQ connection. But with topic, we are unable to progress.
In WAS, we can have client ID, but how do we define it in tomcat.

Screenshot
[WAS Client ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrN69.jpg)

For topic, it is define in context.xml

`<Resource name="jms/xcsInTopicDSL_Ref" auth="Container" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicFactory" SCPHS="cipher" TOP="topic_name"/>`

Error in tomcat logs
`3814741 [WARN] DefaultMessageListenerContainer: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic:topic_name' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSCC0101: The client ID cannot be null.`

Comment: Also there are two topic resource , so I believe clientID have to be different.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using [OpenLiberty](http://openliberty.io/) for WebSphere migrations rather that Tomcat. It is also open source, but has much better compatibility with WAS and JEE APIs as it is full JEE compliant. And if you dont need full JEE it is also composable so you can choose what features do you need.